# Angular JS loginController bind with loginService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am trying to call the loginService from my loginController, but I am receiving this as return:

> ReferenceError: loginService is not defined

loginController.js:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', LoginCtrl]);

function LoginCtrl($scope){   
    $scope.login = function(){
        $scope.msgTxt = '';
        $scope.login = function(user){
            loginService.login(user, $scope); //call login service
        };
    }
}
```

loginService.js:

```
app.factory('loginService', function($http){
    return{
        login:function(user, scope){
            var $promise = $http.post('data/user.php', user); //send data to user.php
            $promise.then(function(msg){
                if(msg.data=='success'){ scope.msgTxt = "Login Succeded";}
                else {scope.msgTxt = "Login Failed";}
            });
        }
    }
});
```

both .js are being called on index.html. The login form is appended on the header of my page as a directive.

Do i have to pass the service as a parameter to the controller? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to pass the service to the controller, like this:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService',
  function ($scope, loginService) {   
    $scope.login = function(){
      $scope.msgTxt = '';
      $scope.login = function(user){
          loginService.login(user, $scope); //call login service
      };
    }
}]);
```

Comment: thanks jessepinho, it worked like a charm ;)
waiting to vote +1 =)